# When is a duplicate not a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

We have a question that has been marked as a duplicate. The question is:

> [When did the “Great War” become “World War 1”?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/39630/24858)

The suggested duplicate is here:

> [When was the term for WW2 first used and was it more popular in,
>   say, US before Europe?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/39626/24858)

The problem is that the question is not actually a duplicate, and the suggested answer on the second question doesn't answer the first.

---

The suggested answer quotes an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102330/when-did-world-war-2-start-being-called-world-war-2) from English:SEW

> OED says that the Manchester Guardian coined "World War No. 2" on 18
>   February 1919, "with reference to an imagined future war arising out
>   of the social upheaval consequent upon the First World War (1914-18)."

That mention of *The First World War* is a commentary on the answer by the Oxford English Dictionary. In fact, the [article](https://www.newspapers.com/image/258364757/) in Manchester Guardian doesn't mention "*World War 1*" or the "*First World War*" at all (the newspaper is hosted on Newspapers.com. It requires a subscription to view, but they offer 7 days free access if you register).

---

In fact, The first public use of the phrase "*First World War*" seems to have been in the title of [memoirs](https://archive.org/details/firstworldwar19100repi) published in 1920, and the first public use of the phrase "*World War 1*" appears to have been by [Time Magazine](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/0,9263,7601390612,00.html) in June 1939. However, this still doesn't quite answer the question. In 1920, and even in 1939, the term "*The Great War*" was still far more common in general use.

Interestingly, various people have done analyses to discover when the terms "*First World War*" and "*World War 1*" became more popular than "*The Great War*" in general use. I wasn't able to find one that would stand up to rigorous academic scrutiny (sources of potential bias in the data are obvious in every example I found), but [this article](http://discontents.com.au/when-did-the-great-war-become-the-first-world-war/) does contain a nice interactive graph.

The suggestion is that use of "*First World War*" and "*World War 1*" overtook the phrase "*The Great War*" in general use in about 1941.

Interestingly, the question is not as trivial as it first appeared.

---

Which is all fine and, if the question hadn't been closed as a duplicate, I might well have posted it as an answer. Which brings me to my question:

> **Why was the question closed as a duplicate in the first place?**

---

EDIT: I'm happy to report that the question has now been re-opened.

Comment: Interesting. If the two terms went hand-in-hand (which I had always assumed) then I think the latter question did kind of devolve to a subset of the former. But if you're saying that's not actually the case...

Comment: @T.E.D. The first known use of the phrase "_The First World War_" is in an [officer's diary](http://qi.com/infocloud/the-first-world-war) from 1918. Also, it is worth noting that, even as late as the 1950s, the "_Second World War_" was often called "_The Second Great War_".

Comment: I'm happy to see that this question has now been reopened. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a strange one. There were some forward thinking people that were "looking ahead" to a "second" war in 1919-1920 when the first was barely over. On the other hand, there were a large number of people that didn't make a connection between "first" and "second" until the "second" was well underway, perhaps almost over, in the early to mid 1940s.

Thus, it was hard to get a consensus as to when "people" started differentiating between the first and the second. Because some were thinking about the "second" before others realized that there had been a "first."

Which is why the question was not a duplicate, even though one might logically assume that it was. Which is why I voted to re-open.

Comment: My thinking too. Although a surprising number still voted to leave the question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: This was a hard issue to parse. It was hard for most people to "get it." Hopefully this discussion helped.